# Terraform: Docker provider ignores update of image digest

Tags: docker, terraform, docker-swarm

I try to configure my Docker service via Terraform in the way, that when the Docker image is updated and the new image digest is available in the remote registry, with `terraform apply` I expect Terraform to detect the digest update and to update the running service.

I applied the configuration from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/registry_image so that my Terraform script looks like this:

```
(...)
data "docker_registry_image" "my-docker-image" {
  name = "my-registry/docker/my-image:2.263.3"
}

resource "docker_image" "docker-image" {
  name = data.docker_registry_image.my-docker-image.name
  pull_triggers = [data.docker_registry_image.my-docker-image.sha256_digest]
  keep_locally = true
}  
(...)

resource "docker_service" "my-service" {
  name = "my-service"

  task_spec {
    container_spec {
      image = data.docker_registry_image.my-docker-image.name
(...)
```

And then I execute Terraform, it is clearly to see that the digest from the remote registry differs from the digest used in the running container:

```
data.docker_registry_image.my-docker-image: Refreshing state... [id=sha256:d7aa8259d1503b970b14c66a06d144200d8f14a6c7f17d62cbfdad815309c9fb]

docker_image.my-docker-image: Refreshing state... [id=sha256:710bf0daf1b66543943dc086cfb3041000bb219aaf00ec75a8c18c770f4cb776my-registry/docker/my-image:2.263.3]
```

You can see that both digests are different, but Terraform claims that:

```
No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

Which is not true, because the digest from `docker_registry_image` is different then from `docker_image`.

The configuration seems to be simple but I still cannot configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I misunderstood the purpose of pulling images when the digest has changed. The digest checksum is only to indicate that there is a newer version of the image, nothing else. Terraform will not update anything (it can only download the newer version to the local registry), because the version of the image did not change, only the digest in the Docker registry.
In other words, if you want to update your service with a newer version of the image, you have to update the version of the image, not just update the existing version, because the digest will be discovered, but the service will not be updated.